# Why does the for loop showing last part of the output?

Tags: c, for-loop

I'm working on my study for passing class. I've done everything, but my foor loop doesn't work well, what should i do for fixing it?

inside of 4th for loop, first loop (a) starts from 9, second loop (b) starts from 3. Why?

#### Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>


int main () {

    int i,j,a,b;

    for(a=0; a<=10; a++){
        for(b=0; b<=10; b++){
            for(i=0; i<=3; i++){
                for(j=0; j<=3; j++){
                    printf("a: %d -- b: %d -- i: %d -- j: %d \n",a,b,i,j);
                }//--j for--    
            }//--i for--    
        }// --b for--
    }// --a for--

    getch ();
    return 0;
}
```

#### Output:

[image]

Comment: Its working perfectly fine in my comp.

Comment: Are you kidding? It is working perfectly.

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit more on the question,because the code seems to be fine..

Comment: `./a.out > out.txt` then see out.txt by editor.

Comment: then why it doesnt work in my comp? interesting..

Comment: I flagged it to close as "unclear..."

Comment: @AhmetÖzdemir See [this](https://ideone.com/dUZovH).

Comment: @AhmetÖzdemir are you checking the output in the console? It truncates the output if there is too much. Redirect it to a text file like bluepixy suggested and it'll show everything.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/NTVx1mS.jpg this is what i get

Comment: You're getting this becuase the output is trucated. Follow what bluepixy suggested.

Comment: @RaphaelMiedl Compiling single file...
--------
- Filename: C:\Users\Ahmet's PC\Desktop\Untitled2sss.c
- Compiler Name: TDM-GCC 4.9.2 64-bit Release

Processing C source file...

Compilation results...
--------
- Errors: 0
- Warnings: 0
- Output Filename: C:\Users\Ahmet's PC\Desktop\Untitled2sss.exe
- Output Size: 128,1015625 KiB
- Compilation Time: 0,33s

Comment: @AhmetÖzdemir add this line as the first line of your main, then see the output in file: `freopen("output.txt","w",stdout);`

Comment: @manetsus yes it worked, than, this means, code is working, but doesnt show everything in console

Comment: @AhmetÖzdemir Terminal has a limited buffer. So, it truncates the previous output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are seeing the output in the console and every console provides a limited buffer memory.

So, the previous outputs were generated, but they are truncated in the consoled you showed.

You can get the full output in a file named `output.txt` by adding the following line as the first line of your main() function:

```
freopen("output.txt","w",stdout);
```

Or, from linux console, you can write the following command as @BLUEPIXY said in the comment:

```
./a.out > out.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

Your program is fine, but it prints 1936 lines of output very quickly, so you only see the last 25 or so and scrolling back, you cannot get back to the beginning of the output because the Windows terminal seems to have very limited backscroll capability, maybe 150 lines.

You can try and increase the backscroll capability in the Windows settings pages (I have not used Windows for many years, I do not know where to do that nor if it can be done).

There are other methods to convince yourself that the code is fine:

- redirect the output to a file and load that file:  open a terminal window and type `myprogram > output.txt` in the terminal.  You agree going to need to hit the keyboard because of the `getch()` at the end of the `main` function.  As a matter of fact, you could remove this line altogether.  As mentioned by manetsus, redirection can be forced from within the program by calling `freopen("output.txt", "w", stdout);` before the first `for` loop.
- pipe the output through `more`.  Again open a terminal window and type `myprogram | less`.  The call to `getch()` is counterproductive for this too.
- move the `getch()` to the end of the second loop (just before `}// --b for--`).  The program will produce 16 lines at a time and wait for a key.